# Loading failed for package 'eRm'

Tags: r, package

When trying to load the 'eRm' package (clean install of R version 4.0.4 / R-Studio 1.3.959 on macOS 10.14.6) by command `library(eRm)` I get:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘eRm’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  no package called ‘mnormt’
```

I uninstalled eRm and reinstalled it with all dependencies. I installed package mnormt as well:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary source needs_compilation
mnormt  2.0.0  2.0.1              TRUE
```

but without success.
What else I can do to solve the issue?

EDIT:

Thanks to the hint of user @G5W I realised that package mnormt wasn't correctly compiled:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mnormt.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mnormt’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/mnormt’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘mnormt’ had non-zero exit status
```

Solution:
Being on macOS 10.14.6, I had to install compiler tools as described here: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ and the everything worked. Thank you very much, @G5W you pointed into the correct direction.

Comment: Did you try to install `mnormt` explicitly?

Comment: Yes, I installed it explicitly and added this information to my original question.

Comment: After you installed `mnormt`,  can you load it with `library(mnormt)` ?

Comment: Oh no, it can't be loaded. I took a look into the logs and saw that mnormt wasn't compiled correctly (I updated my original question). Don't know how to deal with this kind of issue …

Comment: Are you on Windows or another platform?

Comment: I am on macOS and I found the solution: I had to install compiler tools as described here: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ and the everything worked. Thank you very much, @G5W you pointed into the correct direction.